# “TypeError: float argument required, not dict” Error when using .format method

Tags: python, python-requests, string.format

I'm trying to output data relevant to an http request in a string:

```
r = requests.post(url, data, params)
assert r.status_code == 200, '\nurl - {}\nresponse status - {}\nrequest headers - {}\nrequest body - {}\nresponse headers - {}\nresponse body - {}'.format(
        r.url, r.status_code, r.request.headers, r.request.body, r.headers, r.text)
```

Running this on my local machine (python 2.7.5) works great, all of the relevant data is presented and formatted.

When executing this from a Jenkins build job, it returns the exception:

> ```
>       assert r.status_code == 200, '\nurl - {url}\nresponse status - {status}\nrequest headers - {r_headers!s}\nrequest body - {r_body}\nresponse headers - {headers}\nresponse body - {body}'.format(
>             url=r.url, status=r.status_code, r_headers=r.request.headers, r_body=r.request.body, headers=r.headers,
>             body=r.text)
>        TypeError: float argument required, not dict
> ```
>
> test_watch.py:58: TypeError

Through a bit of debugging by changing the .format method to only report one variable at a time, I found the Jenkins job is having a problem with the string formatting while inserting the request headers.  Yes, it is a dict, but the .format() method should handle this just fine.  Why is it complaining about types?

The full traceback isn't terribly helpful:

> ```
>       assert r.status_code == 400, 'Negative test failure' \
>                                      '\nurl - {url}\nresponse status - {status}\nrequest headers - {r_headers!s}\nrequest body - {r_body}\nresponse headers - {headers}\nresponse body - {body}'.format(
>             url=r.url, status=r.status_code, r_headers=r.request.headers, r_body=r.request.body, headers=r.headers,
>             body=r.text)
> ```
>
> E           TypeError: float argument required, not dict

test_watch.py:58: TypeError

To summarize: This works on my local machine, the request headers are outputted in the string:

```
assert r.status_code == 400, 'Negative test failure' \
                                 '\nrequest headers - {r.request.headers}'.format(r=r)
```

Running the same code from a Jenkins build server:

> ```
>       assert r.status_code == 400, 'Negative test failure' \
>                                      '\nrequest headers - {r.request.headers}'.format(r=r)
>        TypeError: float argument required, not dict
>        test_watch.py:58: TypeError
> ```

Update: I changed the code to catch the TypeError, and then raised a custom AssertionError, being built the same way from the same parts (I copy/pasted).  This is terribly confusing, why does .format work one way, but completely fail the other?

```
try:
            assert r.status_code == 400, 'Negative test failure' \
                                         '\nurl - {r.url}\nresponse status - {r.status_code}\nrequest headers - {r.request.headers}\nrequest body - {r.request.body}\nresponse headers - {r.headers}\nresponse body - {r.text}'.format(r=r)
except TypeError as e:
            message = 'TypeError raised! {}'.format(e)
            message += '\nurl - {r.url}\nresponse status - {r.status_code}\nrequest headers - {r.request.headers}\nrequest body - {r.request.body}\nresponse headers - {r.headers}\nresponse body - {r.text}'.format(r=r)
            raise AssertionError(message)
```

When this code is executed, I get:

```
E               AssertionError: TypeError raised! float argument required, not dict
E               url - http://api4.qa.ebay.com/user/v1/watchlist/watch?listingStatus=BLARGLE&limit=25
E               response status - 200
E               request headers - {<good headers outputted as a dict>}
E               request body - <good content here>
E               response headers - {no problems}
E               response body - {all my data was printed!}
```

Comment: Just a tip for `format`, you can use it like so `'name: {me.name}, age {me.age}'.format(me=some_object)`.

Comment: Have you tried splitting it into 5 separate `format` calls to verify that it's the `{headers}` part, instead of just guessing?

Comment: It's a good idea to post the whole traceback, incase you missed something relevant in there that we'd spot.

Comment: Just adding to @abarnert 's point: _how_ do you know exactly what is throwing the TypeError?

Comment: OK, I can't see any way to get `float argument required, not dict` out of `str.format`. Even if you explicitly used a `{headers:f}`, you'd get `non-empty format string passed to object.__format__` (because `dict` doesn't have an override for `__format__`). (You'll get a slightly different error in 2.6, because it'll first convert the dict to a `str` and then try to `f` that instead, but it still won't be the one you're reporting.)

Comment: That error message _is_ what you get from `%`-formatting. So… is this your actual code? Maybe you had some older code that used `%`, you've since updated it to use `{}`, but you forgot to save/deploy/install/whatever it, so you're still testing the older code?

Comment: I'm not using the % formatting, and never have.  My code is and always has been using the {} method of string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why this error was occurring, but I was able to resolve it:

The original Jenkins instance was running my job on Mac OS 10.9.4.  Setting up my job to run in a new slave on 10.9.5 allowed my code to succeed with no changes.

Is there a known issue between OSX 10.9.4 and 10.9.5?